# Hyperbolic metric of arbitrary curvature.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I've been trying to find this online, in books, etc, but I can never find the expression for the metric on the **unit** disk

$$\mathbb{D} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$$

that has **constant curvature $K < -1$**. Everywhere people just do $K = -1$. I'd really appreciate the exact expression in natural cartesian coordinates. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things scale in a reasonable way: The metric
$$ds^2 = \frac{4}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}(dx^2 + dy^2)$$
has $K=-1$. The metric
$$ds_c^2 = \frac{c^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}(dx^2 + dy^2)$$
has $K=-4/c^2$.

Comment: I like to think of this as demonstrating that the units of curvature are inverse area.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, Gauss-Bonnet makes that point.